# Having some problems with Serial.write in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm learning Arduino and programming some basic stuff just to exercise, but I'm stuck with a RGB LED. I'll link the code in order for you to see what's happening.

```c
int RGB_R = A5,
RGB_G = A4,
RGB_B = A3;
    
void setup() {
  pinMode(RGB_R, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_G, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_B, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
      Serial.write(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
      for(int k = 0; k < 256; k++){
        RGB_COLOR(i,j,k);
      }
    }
  }  
}

void RGB_COLOR(int R, int G, int B){
  analogWrite(RGB_R, R);
  analogWrite(RGB_G, G);
  analogWrite(RGB_B, B);
}
```

I want to change the color of the RGB slowly as `i, j and k` increment, but it's changing between 2 colors. Another problem that I'm having is that I can't print in Serial what's the value of `i, j and k`.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: The pins you chose are analog inputs.  They are not analog outputs.  You cannot use analogWrite on them or it will simply default to a digitalWrite.  Try using pins that have PWM ability.

Comment: You should also study up on the difference between Serial.write and Serial.print.  Here you probably want print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to provide some delay after setting the RGB_COLOR

because the code excuted fast and you can't see the change add a `delay` function it will be slower changeing

```
void loop() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
      for(int k = 0; k < 256; k++){
        // sending data to pc
        Serial.print("\ti= ");Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print("\tj= ");Serial.print(j);
        Serial.print("\tk= ");Serial.println(k);
        // change the data
        RGB_COLOR(i,j,k);
        delay(100); // wait for 100 ms
      }
    }
  }

}
```

### update :

you have to connect pins on PWM pin ... if you use arduino uno it will be  (10,11,6,5,3) and change the connection

```
int RGB_R = 10,
    RGB_G = 11,
    RGB_B = 6;
```

### the full code

connect the pins on (10,11,6) ... because [analogWrite](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) only work correctlly with pwm pins

```
int RGB_R = 10,
    RGB_G = 11,
    RGB_B = 6; 
    
void setup() {
  pinMode(RGB_R, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_G, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_B, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
      for(int k = 0; k < 256; k++){
        // sending data to pc
        Serial.print("\ti= ");Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print("\tj= ");Serial.print(j);
        Serial.print("\tk= ");Serial.println(k);
        // change the data
        RGB_COLOR(i,j,k);
        delay(100); // wait for 100 ms
      }
    }
  }

}


void RGB_COLOR(int R, int G, int B){
  analogWrite(RGB_R, R);
  analogWrite(RGB_G, G);
  analogWrite(RGB_B, B);
}
```

Comment: I have just tried doing this, but was not the answer. The LED keeps beeping from green to turned off.

Comment: @JoãoVítor change the pin to pwm pins .... which arduino you use ? ... anlog write will only work on pwm pin

Comment: The Serial.print() worked fine, I dont get why the way I wrote wasnt working, do you have any idea?

Comment: change the pin mumper

Comment: In my first try, I was using Digital (PWM) pins, but I thought that I was just going to send HIGH or LOW data to the LED, and wasnt going to recognise the amount of RGB it was supposed to send. And I am using a Arduino UNO

Comment: @JoãoVítor try the full code with the pin (10,11,6) and tell me if it work or  not ?

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot for the patience ant the help. I will search more about PWE pins, beacuse I thought that all digital pins were PWE too.